# Why aren't my @property decorators working?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator

I'm working on this little Class, playing with the @property decorators. For some reason it's not working right.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    @property 
    def rank(self):
        return self._rank

    @rank.setter
    def rank(self, value):
        valid_ranks = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "J", "Q", "K", "A"]
        if valid_ranks.index(value):
            self._rank = value

    @property
    def suit(self):
        return self._suit

    @suit.setter
    def suit(self,value):
        self._suit = value

    def show(self):
        print "{}{}".format(self.rank, self.suit)
```

I initialize an object like so: `Card("cheese", "ball")`, and presumably this should throw an error. Python happily just rolls with it though and assigns "cheese" to rank. What's going on here? All other calls to the rank setter through assignment syntax seem to happily ignore the setter I've put in place. I'm running Python 2.7.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using old-style classes. As noted in [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property), properties don't work with old-style classes. Derive your classes from `object`. E.g.:

```
class Card(object):
    ...
```

In Python 3 you don't need to do this, because Python 3 only has new-style classes.

Comment: Whoops. I didn't catch that when i looked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing the `rank` and `suit` attributes without underscores but your property methods have `_rank` and `_suit`.

Also `list.index` throws an error if an item is not in the list. You should instead do

```
if value in valid_ranks:
```

Comment: The former is not a problem; he *wants* the `__init__` to call the setters. The latter is not *this* problem.

Comment: Ah... I would never have noticed that! Should I delete my answer?

Comment: After looking for 'delete' I realize that comment might come across as sarcasm... it's not :S